# Uncaught Exception in google analytics using Easytracker

Tags: android, google-analytics, easytracker

**I am using just this in every Activity:**

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(this);
}
```

and going through this [doc](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/exceptions)

**I found out:**

Using EasyTracker
   
To automatically track all uncaught exceptions in your app using EasyTracker, add this line to your analytics.xml file:

```
<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
```

After tracking an exception using automatic exception tracking, EasyTracker will pass the exception on to the Thread's default exception handler.

**When using automatic exception tracking, keep in mind the following:**

1. All exceptions tracked via automatic exception tracking are reported
   as fatal in Google Analytics.
2. The description field is automatically populated using the stack
   trace.

But when i get an UncaughtException and the application crashes, in the Google Analytics description, it just shows:

```
An error occured while executing doInBackground()
```

not the Stack Trace as mentioned in the above points. Any thing needs to be added??

Thank You

Comment: This is the best solution I found so far: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14009883/exception-stack-trace-lost-in-google-analytics-v2-for-android

Comment: Upvoting this, I am facing the same issue. I don't understand why Easytracker shows only the last line of the stack trace...

Comment: Exact same situation here.  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @mattblang I am using [ACRA](http://acra.ch/)

Comment: I use a solution called AppBugTracker is more or less like Acra but without the overhead to create your site to collect information and have some  helper class to not only capture the uncaucht exception but olso the exception more relevant for you.
Have also graphics report and email reports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use an open source tool called [ACRA](http://acra.ch/) for uncaught exception reporting.
It provides significantly more information than Google Analytics or Flurry do, and submits reports to a Google Doc, to which you can get email notification for every report added.

I use Google Analytics for the rest.

Comment: Do you use something like Bugsense with ACRA? I use ACRA also but is not good to see errors in the spreadsheet

Comment: For each release I've backed up the proguard dump files, and wrote a small script to retrace the stack trace against the correct dump. 

I've migrated to Crashlytics later. It has a capture ability like ACRA, and does the retracing automatically.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a custom exception parser to get the whole stacktrace

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils;
import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.ExceptionParser;

public class AnalyticsExceptionParser implements ExceptionParser {

public String getDescription(String p_thread, Throwable p_throwable) {
    return "Thread: " + p_thread + ", Exception: " +     ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(p_throwable);
}
}
```

and set this as default in you activity, like

```
public void setupGoogleAnalyticsCrashReportParser() {

    EasyTracker.getInstance().setContext(this);

    Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler uncaughtExceptionHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    if (uncaughtExceptionHandler instanceof ExceptionReporter) {
        ExceptionReporter exceptionReporter = (ExceptionReporter) uncaughtExceptionHandler;
        exceptionReporter.setExceptionParser(new AnalyticsExceptionParser());
    }
}
```

Hope this helps to someone.